# Search by size in Lucene

Tags: search, lucene, size

I have a problem with my search.

I want to search at a range of sizes, but it does not work.

Size: [0 TO 1000] and I show the files which have a size of between 0 and 1000.

Is it possible to do a search of this type in Lucene?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When searching on field with a range of numbers you have to first make sure, the field is of numeric type when indexing a document and adding the size field.
While searching (if you have trouble with the syntax) you can create a `RangeQuery`, and combine multiple ranges with `BooleanQuery`.